# Noodlejs won't install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install noodlejs using npm on Windows and I'm receiving the following error messages:

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd" install noodlejs
npm WARN engine noodlejs@0.3.1: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.32","npm":"1.4.28"})

> node-expat@2.0.0 install C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Node\node_modules\noodlejs\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Node\node_modules\noodlejs\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
gyp
npm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "noodlejs"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
Process finished with exit code 1 at 19:44:25.
Execution time: 23,672 ms.

> node-gyp rebuild
Cannot run program "node-gyp" (in directory "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Node"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried executing this command as administrator?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio (at least Express) 2010 or newer installed (with the Windows SDK if you have Express)?

Comment: try `npm install --msvs_version=2012 noodlejs`